# Trying to get property of non object returns Json but can't access the table field

Tags: laravel

When i do {{$user->detail}} the data returns the json properties but when I say {{$user->detail->file_name}} it says trying to get property of non object.

these are my codes:

```
AdminController.php

  public function __construct(UserRepository $UserRepository, User $user) {
        $this->UserRepository = $UserRepository;
        $this->user = $user;
    }


   public function showPendingApplications(Request $request){
       $elderly = $this->UserRepository->getPendingElderly();
       $messenger = $this->UserRepository->getPendingMessenger();
       $pending = $this->UserRepository->getAllPendingApplications();
       return view('admin.show-pending-applications', compact('elderly','messenger','pending'));
   }
```

UserRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Admin;

use App\User;

class UserRepository {

    public function __construct(User $user) {
        $this->model = $user;
    }

    public function activateUser($request, $id) {
        $user = User::where('id', $id)->update(['confirmation' => true]);
        return $user;
    }

    public function deleteUser($id) {
        $user = User::where('id', $id)->delete();
        return $user;
    }

    public function getUserProfile($id)
    {
        return $this->model
        ->leftJoin('user_details','users.id','=','user_details.user_id')->first();
    }

    public function getPendingElderly(){
        return $this->model
        ->where(['confirmation' => false])
        ->where('role_id', '=', 2)
        ->get();
    }

    public function getPendingMessenger(){
        return $this->model
        ->where(['confirmation' => false])
        ->where('role_id', '=', 3)
        ->get();
    }

    public function getAllPendingApplications() {
        return $this->model
        ->where(['confirmation' => false])
        ->whereIn('role_id', [2, 3])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
    }

    public function getAllUsers(){
        return $this->model
        ->where(['confirmation'=> true])
        ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
        ->get();
    }

    public function getMatchedListing()
    {

    }

}
```

view:
https://gyazo.com/c1260ea91cf4267a380753aca9400b4c

I had this right few days ago but I think i deleted some code when I made some changes in my repository

Comment: can you show the $user->detail json properties please

Comment: https://gyazo.com/564565bc3fd80d807c7de7a2c10b6c35